# How to restrict windows tasks to weekdays only?

Tags: windows, windows-task-scheduler

I have a task that triggers on "user session logon". I now want to restrict that task to fire only on weekdays, and being ignored on the weekend.

Is that possible?

Sidenote: I cannot use the trigger `on schedule` as I do not want to run the task periodically, but only on **logon**, and only on **weekdays**.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/513676/is-it-possible-to-schedule-a-task-only-on-working-days/513679

Answer (score 25):

1. click Weekly (NOT Daily)
2. Choose the days you want

Comment: But it should run only on logon during weekdays. Not just every weekday at a specific time.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand, this is not possible using the task scheduler alone.

You could use a piece of VBScript to achieve this.

Set up a file, e.g. `mytask.vbs`, like this:

```
If DatePart("w", Date, vbMonday) < 6 Then
    Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    WScript.Quit(Shell.Run("C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe", 10, True))
End If
```

Replace notepad by the task you actually want to run. What this things does is: It checks whether the current day is Mo-Fr (this is done by specifying the start of the week as Monday, so `DatePart` will return values from 1=Monday to 7=Sunday, and then we're checking if it's below 6), and if yes, it runs a certain program, waits for it to finish and forwards its exit code. (The magic number `10` here means that it will respect whatever setting for window display (normal, maximized, minimzed) was passed by the task scheduler, if any, and also forward it to the program.)

Then you can create a scheduled task with a logon trigger only, which runs `wscript.exe /e:vbscript c:\path\to\your\mytask.vbs`. That's it!

Comment: Excellent solution if you want a repeating task to not run on weekends.